# Is there a design pattern for an object representing a row from a query result?

Tags: sql, design-patterns, orm

## Case in point

Suppose that I make a complex query a database from an application, either by plain SQL or by a an ORM library:

```
SELECT user.name, book.title, home.address
       FROM user 
       JOIN book on user.book_id = book.id
       JOIN home on book.home_id = home.id;
```

The result is a list of `(name, title, address)` tuples.

It is often convenient to initialize an object from each row, a-la:

```
def Shipping(object):
    def __init__(self, row):
        self.name = row[0]
        self.title = row[1]
        self.address = row[2]

    def action(self):
        return "Sending %s to %s at %s" % (self.book, self.user, self.address)
```

## The question

**Is there a design pattern for an object that represents a row in a DB query?**

## Notes

- Following the [Active Record answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35893740/51197): This case is different. An [Active Record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) refers to a row in a table, and it is tied to the DB. This means that changes in the object can be materialized in the DB. My case discusses an object that reflects a query, which might be the result of a complicated JOIN. The resulting object is not related to the database, and changes in it can not be reflected back to it.

Comment: [DTO](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) comes to mind, but it's not much of a 'pattern' actually.

Answer (score 1):

[The Active Record pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) represents each database row with an object (although it gives that object the ability to update the database, which you didn't specify).

Comment: Dave, apologies for the late response, just saw your answer. As you've noted, my case is different than the Active Record. The former fetches an arbitrary query result (might be a JOIN), and retains no relation to the DB. The later associates a DB row with an object, and retains a DB connection.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Might want to call that out in words in the question.